# java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host No address associated with hostname

Tags: java, android

When API call from background service and mobile screen is off. Got
the following error.

> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve
>   host: No address associated with hostname
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
>                     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>                     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
>                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
>                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
>                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
>                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
>                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
>                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
>                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
>                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:161)
>
> ```html
>  When API call from background service and mobile screen is off. Got the following error.
> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "": No address associated with hostname
> W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
>                   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>                   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
>                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
>                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
>                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
>                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
>                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
>                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
>                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
>                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:161)
> ```

Comment: post your code also..

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already done so, add the permissions to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I think that's the most common cause of this UnknownHostException error message. Another possible cause is that your Internet connection is actually down.

Comment: It's work fine but when i call api in service then after some time i get this error. Again when i resume the app from background it's working fine in service.

Comment: I think,when app is in background and then internet connection lost then api call is not working. Suggest me in another way to call api in service when app in background,